# Having trouble using a function of a var set twice in an output statement in minizinc

Tags: minizinc

The following program runs with no problem.

```
array[1..2] of var set of 5..8: ar = [{5, 6}, {6, 7}];

function string: format_set_1( var set of int: s ) = "\(fix(s))\t";  
function string: format_set_2( var set of int: s ) = "\(fix(s))\t";  

output
   [format_set_1(ar[1]) ++ format_set_2(ar[2])];
```

But when I replace `format_set_2` with `format_set_1` (or vice versa) in the output array I get the following error message.

```
MiniZinc: type error: 
function with the same type already defined in C:/Users/rabbott/AppData/Local/Temp/MiniZinc IDE (bundled)-SEkuWd/untitled_model.mzn:4.1
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by a bug in MiniZinc 2.3.2. The issue was recently raised on [GitHub](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues/323) and has been fixed on the [MiniZinc develop branch](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/commit/646cc47e8cda1be61b3bcd9544c1e391326ddd7c). The next release of MiniZinc should again work as expected.